# JS: Proper way for creating functions and declaring inside $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jQuery code stops working properly when I add a declaration to my jQuery code that alone, works fine.

This is my entire code that without the first lines works fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  /////////////////////////Without this works fine
  $('[rel=popover]').popover({
    title: 'title',
    placement: 'bottom',
    trigger: 'hover'
  });
  //////////////////////////

//SEARCH PAGE, STICKY SIDEBAR
if (!!$('.sticky').offset()) { // make sure ".sticky" element exists
    $(window).scroll( function() { // scroll event
      var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number 
      if (windowTop > 60){
        $('.sticky').css({ position: 'fixed', top: '60px' }); //60px (header's height)
      } else {
        $('.sticky').css('position','static');
      }
    });
  }

//PARALLAX ON HOMEPAGE
var currentX = '';
var movementConstantCity = .03;
var movementConstantCars = .01;
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if(currentX == '') currentX = e.pageX;
    var xdiff = e.pageX - currentX;
    currentX = e.pageX;
    $('.parallax_city').each(function(i, el) {
        var movement = (i + 1) * (xdiff * movementConstantCity);
        var newX = $(el).position().left + movement;
        $(el).css('left', newX + 'px');
    });
    $('.parallax_cars').each(function(i, el) {
        var movement = (i + 1) * (xdiff * movementConstantCars);
        var newX = $(el).position().left + movement;
        $(el).css('left', newX + 'px');
    });
});

//SHOW FORM ON PUBLISH PAGE
$(".pricing_table ul").click(function(e) {
    if($(".form_details").css('display') === "none") {
        $(".form_details").show();
        $(".preamble").text("Texto!");
        var body = $("html, body");
        body.animate({scrollTop:0}, '400', 'swing');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

//SELECTED PACKAGE ON PUBLISH PAGE
$(".pricing_table ul#package").click(function () { 
$(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass("selected");
     if($(".pricing_table ul#package").hasClass("selected")) {
        $(".pricing_table ul#package .highlight").hide();   
     }
});

});
```

How can I include the first lines correctly?

Comment: What is the error message, or what does "stops working" mean? `popover()` is not part of standard jQuery. Did you forget to load the plugin providing that function?

Comment: What plugin are you using for the .popover() method there? Are you sure its loaded properly in your environment?

Comment: @Mörre and Aweary I'm using bootstrap and I'm declaring this code after declaring bootstrap.js like this: _<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/core.js"></script>_ The previous code is inside core.js

Comment: @Aweary please read above, I couldn't tag you

Comment: @Mörre By "stop working" I mean the code just doesn't act as it should, as if I never wrote it it just does nothing. Only the popover part works when adding it. Not what is after

Comment: Do you get an error message? if you do console.log($('[rel=popover]').popover) does it log anything?

Comment: @Aweary with console.log I get the following: 
_function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this    = $(this)
      var data     = $this.data('bs.popover')
      var options  = typeof option == 'object' && option
      var selector = options && options.selector

      if (!data && option == 'destroy') return
      if (selector) {
        if (!data) $this.data('bs.popover', (data = {}))
        if (!data[selector]) data[selector] = new Popover(this, options)
      }_ **[...]**

Comment: Why don't you add all that information to your question, where you have room and formatting options? And a jsfiddle would be nice, broadens the number of people who will look for the bug for you :)

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question, how you are doing it is the proper way. The question is why is it not working?
I would start by wrapping a try/catch around it and checking the exception. My guess is there is something wrong with loading bootstrap.js

```js
   try {
     $('[rel=popover]').popover({
       title: 'title',
       placement: 'bottom',
       trigger: 'hover'
     });
   } catch (x) {
     console.log(x);
   }
```